# REMOTE_USER empty

Tags: single-sign-on, kerberos

I am trying to enable Single sign on to a web application that is running on Apache 2.4 on centos 7.
The same app can be accessed through Apache on Windows (using mod_auth_sspi), and it is using REMOTE_USER variable to identify users. On apache for windows everything works ok.
I can manually create kerberos tickets from centos so am pretty sure that keytab and kerberos realm settings on centos are ok.
I get an error when I actually try to login to the application (error message is "empty login"). This indicates that REMOTE_USER is not being sent, and I created a php file to test it and it proved to be the case.

```
<html> 
<head> 
<title>hello</title> 
</head> 
<body> 
<h1> 
Hello, this is remote_user: <?php echo( $_SERVER[ 'REMOTE_USER' ] ) ?> | END
</h1> 
</body> 
</html>
```

This returns nothing on centos, whereas on windows the same file returns DOMAIN\user as it should.
It seems as though the authentication module is not working on centos, but I have all the suggested packages installed (mod_auth_kerb, pam_krb, krb5-libs,krb5-workstation). apachectl -M shows auth_kerb as loaded, also LoadModule directive is present in httpd.conf

Can anyone direct me as to how I can check for 100% that kerberos module is working correctly and that it has loaded all the necesary things? Or any other ideas?

Comment: Wrong site, `mod_auth_kerb` is dead. Use `mod_auth_gssapi`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if your issue is solved. However, you can try **mod_auth_ntlm_winbind**. Configure the same and it will help to fetch REMOTE_USER parameter in CentOS 6 and 7

Refer: https://hemakhema.blogspot.ae/2017/07/enable-sso-login-in-linux.html